# How to structure multiple data arrays with Multiple XY Line Chart in c3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

This item has been posted before but I guess I have a different situation:

```html
var allmydata = [
                ['week331', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                ['data331', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],                
                ['week778', 30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
                ['data778', 20, 180, 240, 100, 190],
                ['week225', 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
                ['data225', 10, 150, 220, 160, 300]
    ];

var AllWeeks = ['week331','week778','week225']

var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
           AllWeeks: AllWeeks,
            columns: allmydata
        }
});
```

Obviously I want my weeks to start at week 1 and end (in this case) at week 49.
Currently I get 6 lines (so also a line for each week).
How can I solve this?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: Do you want all data to be displayed as a single line (meaning all 16 data points by merging data331, data778 and data225) over all weeks, or three individual lines representing data 331, 778 and 225? The latter case will it make hard to define your x axis scale/labeling with your weeks.

Comment: No, in this case, I want three lines. The week will be the X axes and Data will be the lines. Like: https://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy_multiple.html

Comment: As I have an issue with my database I cannot test my solution but it looks like this does the trick:
var match = function (dataStr) {
    return dataStr.startsWith("data") ? dataStr.replace ("data", "week") : undefined;
};

var xs = {};
allmydata.forEach (function (series) {
    var seriesName = series[0];
    var xsName = match (seriesName);
    if (xsName) {
        xs[seriesName] = xsName;
    }
});

var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            xs: xs,
            columns: allmydata
        }
});

Comment: I did test your function and it works. Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/38togLjh/ - maybe you could write an answer to provide a solution to others having a similar issue?